# Can MongoDB handle TBs of data?

Tags: mongodb, hbase, bigdata

Will MongoDB handle several TB of data? I've read posts saying that Mongo does well with < 1TB of data, for larger sets I should go with HBase. Is that true?

I need to store and later process several TB of text data.

Answer (score 5):

These may be of interest to you:

- [Wordnik](http://www.10gen.com/customers/wordnik): data set in the >3TB range
- [Craiglist](http://www.10gen.com/customers/craigslist): shard cluster designed to support 10TB of data.

You'll find some additional [case studies](http://www.10gen.com/customers) on 10gen's website, although not all of them provide specific numbers on data set sizes. There are also some older discussions on Stack Overflow about this very question ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2503319/162228) for a blurb about a user with 12TB of data from March 2010), and you'll likely find more case studies scattered among presentations on [Speaker Deck](https://speakerdeck.com/) or [Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/). In short, MongoDB can certainly handle that amount of data (people are using it to that effect today), but you'll want to heed best practices, which is where existing presentations can come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

**MongoDB**

Tens of thousands of organizations use MongoDB to build high-performance systems at scale. Over a third of the Fortune 100 and many of the most successful and innovative web companies rely on MongoDB. They've grown from single server deployments to clusters with over 1,000 nodes, delivering millions of operations per second on over 100 billion documents and petabytes of data.

Scalability is not just about speed. It's about 3 different metrics, which often work together:

Cluster Scale. Distributing the database across 100+ nodes, often in multiple data centers

Performance Scale. Sustaining 100,000+ database read and writes per second while maintaining strict latency SLAs

Data Scale. Storing 1 billion+ documents in the database
There are many examples of MongoDB users who are pushing the limits to scalability. Here are a few, organized around each scaling dimension.

You can find reference about MongoDB: Bringing Online Big Data to
Business Intelligence & Analytics  at this [article](http://s3.amazonaws.com/info-mongodb-com/MongoDB_BI_Analytics.pdf)

Comment: Hi, you had mentioned "Here are a few, organized around each scaling dimension." However this doesn't include any link. Could you please share any such most recent available statistics that can help taking decisions. I'm looking forward to handle approximately 3.5 TB of data with easy scaled up to 5 TB in coming 2 years. Currently I have ES 5.x and MongoDB as candidates. I'm looking forward to data points on why select one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of production clusters which can handle 150TB of data with 100+ shards, all managed on-prem(like a private cloud) using OpsManager